# Use timestamp in Spring configuration

Tags: java, spring, java-8

In Spring configuration can we have a timestamp or uuid to be dynamic value when we start the service?

```
<bean id="atomikosUserTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
          init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownForce">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir">{timestamp}/log/</prop>
                <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir">{timestamp}/log/</prop>
                <!--<prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives">1000</prop>-->
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I would like to put the folder directory with timestamp every time we run the application.

I´m using Spring 4.15 and I cannot upgrade for now.

Regards.

Comment: Did you try [Spring Expression Language](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-beandef) ??

Comment: It´s also in Spring 4.15? Regards.

Comment: As i remember it supporting from 3 version til now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple date try to use SpEL
instead of `{timestamp}`  -> `#{new java.util.Date().toString()}`

Answer (score 2):

Below class has a method returning the current timestamp It'll be executed to get the current timestamp.

```
public class CurrTime {

    public long getCurrTimestamp() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

}
```

In `xml` file create a bean of above class

```
<bean id="currTime" class="path.to.CurrTime"></bean>
```

and then the current timestamp can be accessed as,

```
#{currTime.getCurrTimestamp()}
```

Comment: Good to know, but the answer #{new java.util.Date().toString()} dont require any implementation

Comment: Yes, `#{new java.util.Date().toString()}` is easy to use, however, if any modification is required then a method for that would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

#{T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()}